# Using .htaccess to control HTTPS on certain pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

I've got a site that requires (obviously) HTTPS for checkout.  The current fix put in place involved making the whole site run in SSL mode, but this is causing problems.

How would I change this...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

To only set a certain URL (say basket.php) as HTTPS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I beleive this would work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /basket.php
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 13):

A shorter version:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^basket\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: How could I mod that to accept multiple pages?  Say basket and checkout and blah?

Comment: Change the pattern `^basket\.php$` to whatever you want. If you need help with the regular expression, take a look at [Apache’s mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html).

Comment: "In this document, we attempt to provide enough of a regex vocabulary to get you started, without being overwhelming, in the hope that RewriteRules will be scientific formulae, rather than magical incantations." - heh, that was me to a tee - not anymore, thanks.