# Is it possible to redirect from any subdomain to a specified folder using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect from subdomain to the specified directory using htaccess.

Like:

```
 http://abc.example.com/index.php
```

to

```
http://example.com/index.php
```

but without changing URL.

Comment: So you want to reverse proxy? What you really want to do is to have all your sites pointing to the same place, and using the same vhost so you won't need to mess with any htaccess, any proxying, or any redirecting.

Comment: The similar question is added previosly.

Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216075/rewritecond-and-rewriterule-in-htaccess