# How should I use https in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https

I'm developing an application in Rails (2.3.4) and there are some parts that need to run over a secure protocol, for example, the login form, the credit card form, etc.

1. How can I do just these pages be https, and all other pages remain http?
2. How can I test ssl in development environment?

Answer (score 0):

Configure apache to use SSL for the paths that require it (ie, '/login' etc.).

You'll also need to configure your routes to use https:

`map.resources :login, :requirements => { :protocol => 'https' }`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213404/using-htaccess-to-control-https-on-certain-pages