# How do I go about setting up HTTPS for my site's log-in page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

Rails 2.3.11

I'm not really sure how to start. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775688/how-should-i-use-https-in-ruby-on-rails) here on SO, but the only response didn't elaborate on setting up Apache.

My site's hosted with BlueHost, fyiy.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have SSH access with this solution.

Login via ssh

#### Generate 2048 bit private key

$>openssl genrsa -out host.key 2048

#### Generate signing request

$>openssl req -new -nodes -key host.key -out host.csr

Above command will ask you a bunch of questions. Your input needs to match the domain registration values.

#### Submit contents of host.csr value to SSL provider.

$>cat host.csr

#### You should get back a ".crt" file from the SSL provider. You need to point your sites virtual host at the private key and certificate file/.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/host.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/host.key
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:!SSLv2:!RC4:+EXP
</VirtualHost>
```